# Java - Jackson Yaml - Correct way to define List of Key : Value pairs in an object

Tags: java, jackson-databind

Converting an object to yaml output using jackson

I want:

```
mylist: 
  - key1 : value1
  - key2 : value2
```

I've tried the obvious - defining `List<Map<String, String>>` but that doesn't work as well as I'd hope. I get this:

```
mylist:
 -
  ? key1
  : value1
 -
  ? key2
  : value2
```

I know I can define it as List and concatenate myself, but there has to be a more elegant solution, no?

Comment: how are you reading your yaml? are you using spring or springboot?

Comment: why not just use a `Map` instead?

Comment: I'm converting an object to an output string. 
It's irrelevant how I'm reading it.

And I'm writing configuration to feed into a third party process. It requires the format I stated. As stated. 

If there's a way to get a map to come out looking like the list of KV pairs then I'll gladly use it - I just don't know how to define it.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I defined as a list and concatenated. Life's too short...